# How to change expired LDAP user password under linux?

Tags: linux, ldap, authentication, password, openldap

can somebody give an advice how to change the LDAP password already expired?

I have an LDAP user and the password for this user is expired:

```
# su user
You are required to change your password immediately (password aged)
su: Authentication token is no longer valid; new one required
(Ignored)
```

then I can change the password using 'passwd'. But if I try to login once again, the message still appears. If I try the ssh login, I also get the following message:
"You are required to change your password immediately (password aged)"

Then I change the password. But if I try to login once again, the message remains...

Thank you in advance.

P.S. I have also tried:

```
user@server$ ldappasswd

Please enter your password: 
ldap_sasl_interactive_bind_s: Invalid credentials (49)
additional info: SASL(-13): user not found: no secret in database
```

Comment: Are you able to connect to LDAP server directly? (Got your access and rootdn?)

Comment: yes, I can (I have a root too)

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a few attributes from your `ldappasswd`

This is just an example

```
ldappasswd -x -h <host> -D "<rootdn>" -w <rootdn_password> -s <new_password_for_user> "uid=user,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com"
```

Probably you are using some policies (some of them can be kept in LDAP - for instance you got something like that in your LDAP server configruation)

```
overlay ppolicy
ppolicy_default "cn=default,ou=policies,dc=example,dc=com"
ppolicy_use_lockout
```

Some of them can be kept locally (look for `moduleload ppolicy.la` in LDAP server configuration).

Probably you are also missing ability to allow users to change thier passwords without god's power. You can do it by resetting PAM or (easier way) to allow users to change thier userPassword attribute without authentication.

```
access to attrs=userPassword
        by self write
        by anonymous auth
        by users none

access to * by * read
```

Whenever you need more precise please let me know :)

Comment: the ldappasswd (with all parameters you suggested) runs successfully. After it I can authorise in LDAP with a new password:

ldapsearch -u -v -x -h localhost -D uid=user,ou=Users,dc=aaa,dc=bbb -W

However, 'su user' still says the same: You are required to change your password immediately (password aged)

Comment: Please execute `chage -l user`

Comment: I assume I need to change the expiration date in OpenLDAP rather than with 'chage', because 'chage' says "User is not in /etc/passwd". But I have no idea how... Some good OpenLDAP manual would be helpful

Answer (score 2):

Are you using **shadow*** attributes on the server? If yes make sure **shadowlastchange** attribute is writable by the user(s), otherwise the userpassword attribute get updated and shadowLastchange remains un-changed, on next attempt, the client tools calculate password age using the old shadowLastChange value and think the password needs to be changed.

Comment: yes, I checked, attributes are presented. But can you advice me please, how can I check if attributes are writable / update them?

Comment: Please make sure you use an acl that allows users to write shadowLastChange attribute.                                          For eg: access to dn.subtree="ou=people,dc=example,dc=com"
        attrs=userPassword
        by self write
        by anonymous auth
        by * none
    access to dn.subtree="ou=people,dc=example,dc=com"
        attrs=shadowLastChange
        by self write
        by * read
    access to dn.subtree="dc=example,dc=com"
        by * read

Comment: @user1075993 My previous comment includes a sample acl (sorry.. it's not formatted correctly.. I dont see format options in the comment box) You can always check whether an attribute is writable or not by using ldapmodify utility.